# Shutdown fails after upgrading from lucid to maverick?

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, shutdown, freeze

It didn't happen in my computer, but in my girlfriend's pc. She upgraded to maverick and now it doesn't shutdown properly, the screen just freezes and she has to shutdown pressing and holding the power button. I've tried adding:
`apm power_off=1` to `/etc/modules` and
`acpi=force` to `etc/default/grub` config, but it still doesn't work... By the way, the computer is new, it's just like 3 weeks old so the hardware should not be that outdated.

Comment: Can you be specific as to what you added to /etc/modules?

Comment: Of course, what I added was "apm power_off=1" in /etc/modules. I didn't remember what I put when I wrote the question^^

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 (or more?) ways to turn off a computer, and not all of them work with all hardware.  Apparently on your girlfriend's PC the wrong method is chosen in Maverick.

Best you can do is file a bug against the kernel with the following command (run on the computer with the problem—it will collect necessary info about the hardware, the kernel, etc.):

```
apport-bug linux
```

And answer the questions & explain the problem on the Launchpad site when asked for it.