# New computer hangs on shutdown/reboot, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: kernel

My system is **working perfectly but it freezes during shutdown**/reboot/suspend/hibernate: All windows and the menu bar disappear but the desktop wallpaper remains. It doesn't even show the shutdown screen (the one with the animated dots) where I could hit ESC and watch the shutdown console text. The system is brand-new and fully updated using Update Manager.

1. **How can I determine what is causing the freeze?**
2. **Is there a log I can investigate?**
3. **How can I fix this?**

I see no obvious cause of the freeze. The only USB attachment is a mouse/keyboard; I don't have any external storage attached; and I don't have any programs running (the machine freezes even when doing shutdown right from the login screen).

**What I've tried so far:**

- Based on other questions ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21749/computer-freezes-on-shutdown), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11438/shutdown-fails-after-upgrading-from-lucid-to-maverick), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12979/computer-wont-shut-down)) that suggest some ACPI settings, I've tried `sudo shutdown -h now` to see whether the shutdown console text display offers any hints, but the system doesn't even get that far - it still freezes while the screen shown the desktop background image, without any toolbars. **Only `sudo shutdown --force` works,** but that's not a solution.
- Editing the grub menu to add *acpi=off* to the kernel didn't help. I guess there's not much point in trying the other (lesser) ACPI suggestions?
- Adding *noapic* to the grub entry had no discernible effect. Adding *nolapic* instead did something (I had removed the *quiet* option) - the system managed to continue further with the shutdown, right until the line *Checking for running unattended-upgrades:* which were the last characters on the screen.
- I've also checked the system BIOS, especially regarding power options, but didn't see anything out of the ordinary. Switching the BIOS standby setting from S3 to S1 didn't help. The standby setting can't be disabled, and there are no other ACPI-related settings AFAIK.
- BIOS reset didn't help. Not surprised; hadn't changed anything.
- I tried going to a virtual console (CtrlAltF1) [as suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/525886#525886) by djeikyb and from there did a *shutdown -h now* and it froze there too, after [this console output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/568337/). I didn't try killing processes one at a time because I'm still too newbie to figure out how to do that.
- Booting with kernel 2.6.35.22 rather than 2.6.35.25 didn't help.
- Disabling the Nvidia drivers didn't help.
- Booting from Live CD (USB stick in fact) didn't help; it freezes the same way.
- Booting from Live CD, with `acpi=off noapic nolapic` didn't help either. Neither did just `nolapic`. So evidently this is not some custom setting in my install, but some sort of basic issue.
- MemTest competed in 1 hour without errors.

Comment: Hanging at shutdown/restart shouldn't prevent any kind of installation. Linux is not windows, files can be replaced while in use, Ubuntu will not make the upgrades while rebooting. Reboot is only required to make sure that the new executables are loaded.

Comment: @Javier sorry but I disagree. Some installations and specifically the Nvidia drivers explicitly require steps during shutdown. There's also a step in the normal shutdown procedure that checks for any other pending installations just before reboot. If you're right, why does the Update Manager ask for a reboot, and why does the power menu rename the "reboot" entry to "reboot to finish installing upgrades"? (quoted from memory.) In general I *am* very pleased with Ubuntu and also with the fact that all *programs* can be installed and are available instantly. But for *drivers* it may be different?

Comment: Don't be sorry about disagreement. Knowledge usually comes after disagreement. I can't see any script related to upgrades executed at shutdown but for /etc/init.d/inattended-upgrades, and this just checks if a upgrading is in process and forces shutdown to wait for them to complete. The menu changes because you usually(*) need to reboot to apply the upgrades, the kernel should be reloaded. I don't know about nvidia proprietary driver, but most graphical drivers while start just with an X reboot (and maybe some rmmod).

Comment: @Javier, ah yes "unattended-upgrades" is what I see during shutdown (on my other machine). Thanks for explaining that! :-)

Comment: @torbengb: sorry but, this is not the case. Power menu has that "reboot to finish installation upgrades" is highly misleading and it does not mean what you think. There is _nothing_ that should be do on shutdown to "finish installation" as you may think. That text is intended to mean that you have to reboot to use the new version of some softwares, like new kernel can be installed/upgraded but you still use the older one till a reboot. It does _NOT_ mean that shutdown does any extra step on installation! You are wrong here, even nvidia driver install does not do anything "extra" on shutdown.

Comment: @LGB thanks for clarifying further what Javier also explained. I now understand that the reboot itself does not affect the upgrade process - and that is cool! - But I am still stuck with a system that cannot shut down.

Comment: I agree with you. It's likely an ACPI issue, I hope that the output of a command line shutdown can help. If not, then I was going to suggest to boot with quiet option and look at the shutdown messages.

Comment: @Javier: please put that as an answer.

Comment: @torengb: I prefer that answer are just that answers not request for more info ;). Askubuntu has great placement in Google, this question will be useful for much more people than us. I believe that keeping answers as, well... answers will be more helpful for all of them.

Comment: Check what kernel version is in use. [According to this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25753/not-able-to-suspend-or-hibernate/25784#25784), there's a problem with one version; try another. If that other kernel version works, then the problem has been identified (not solved).

Comment: Try deactivating the proprietary Nvidia driver to see if that interferes.

Comment: Newest kernel is 2.6.35.25. Also available is 2.6.35.22. I've just tried that; problem remains.

Comment: Nope. No impovement here either. But I do need to reconfigure my graphics again :)

Comment: I'm really running out of options here... I dearly hope a solution will present itself. It would be catastrophic to not be able to suspend, or even shutdown! (Meaning back to Windows installation again, which I'd really hate to do.)

Comment: I'd check with the manufacturer to see if theres a BIOS update. Posting the actual model of the computer as well as the BIOS firmware version (command: dmidecode) would be helpful.

Comment: 2* "try this"answers.... shouldn't these be converted to comments or deleted altogether?  **;-)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10489760&postcount=4) has the exact solution! (Why didn't I post there in parallel to here on AU? It would have saved a week of calendar time and several hours of computer time!)

> The wrong driver is loaded which
>   prevents shutdown. To fix it you need
>   to do this:
>
> Open a terminal and type: `sudo modprobe -rf rt2860sta`
>
> Followed by: `sudo modprobe rt2860sta`
>
> Then you need to blacklist the wrong driver:
>   `echo blacklist rt2800pci | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
>
> Once you have rebooted (you will need
>   to do a hard power off for the last
>   time!) you will find you can reboot
>   properly.

Comment: Submit a patch at Launchpad?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'm totally new to Linux, so I'm not sure how to do that. Looking into it...

Comment: I think [this bug has already been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/692696).

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 11.10, you could try the `reboot=bios` option (or other options):

1. Access the GRUB configuration file [as explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.2BAC8-boot.2BAC8-grub.2BAC8-grub.cfg).

   ```
   cd .. && cd .. && sudo -H gedit etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` so it says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=bios"
   ```

   and save the file.
3. Update GRUB to write the configuration:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot your computer

   (it may hang on the purple screen, but hopefully for the last time...)

Comment: You could also try the parameters for ACPI : http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/39504.aspx

Comment: It is always safer to put options on GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT coz it doesn't affect boot entry for recovery mode.

Comment: I had this problem only when rebooting with Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu on an old PC (Intel Celeron, 512 MB RAM). I tried all solutions, but just your answer helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It could be an ACPI problem. You can try to pass the kernel some parameters to disable some of ACPI functions. Note this will result in a loss of features (power management) or performance (lots of polling).

First a little explanation about how to add some kernel parameters, robbed miserably from [Htorque](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up/25024#25024):

1. Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after starting the system).
2. Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the <kbd>c</kbd> key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.
3. Go down to the line starting with `linux` and add one of the following parameters after a space.
4. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

You cant try the following options, one each time, they are ordered from more aggressive, likely to work to less aggressive but less functions disabled:

- `acpi=off` , this one should completely disable acpi. It's the most likely to work, but you will lose all your power management.
- `pci=noacpi` , this will make the kernel to ignore acpi for pic scanning and irq assignment.
- `acpi=noirq`, this will only disable irq assignment through acpi.
- `irqpoll`, this will make the kernel poll for all unattended irq interruptions.
- `noapic`, this will make the kernel ignore the [APIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller).

Comment: Too long for a comment

Comment: If you like the how-to add kernel parameters, don't forget to vote for the original Htorque answer.

Comment: I edited the topmost entry and added *acpi=off* to the end of the line starting with *linux*. I noticed that the line wrapped to another line so I actually added it to that following line - not in the middle. I then booted with that entry and chose *restart* right from the login screen - and it immediately froze again...

Comment: Try noapic and nolapic, both are not acpi related.

Comment: *noapic* = no effect. *nolapic* worked up to a point, see updated question.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this by adding the following line to the file `/etc/default/halt`:

```
INIT_HALT = POWEROFF
```

Comment: Thank you it really worked!!!. I still cannot find out which package really brought this nuisance. I was aware of each packages as I installed them. It started to show when I had installed virtualbox (I later thought it was due to mpd). I cannot really determine how to revert it.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- reseat RAM chips
- reset BIOS to defaults
- try to run Live distro and see how it works
- run MemTest for awhile

Comment: Live distro didn't help; same effect. BIOS reset didn't help; same effect. MemTest is planned for tonight. Reseating the RAM requires breaking the seal; I'd rather not, as this is a brand new machine.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases this happens due to buggy graphics card. E.g In ubuntu 12.04, I had to install all updates (including the ones related to xorg). After that, I installed catalyst 12.10, which solved the problem. I suggest you remove (if installed) laptop-mode-tools (including its dependencies i.e ethtool, sdparm), because it also causes the shutdown to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough my problem was resolved when I removed the parameter "now". That is, I was using:

```
sudo /sbin/reboot now
```

and it was getting stuck,

but when I used:

```
sudo /sbin/reboot
```

the problem was solved.

I don't understand why. The problem appeared only when I installed **Ubuntu 13.10**.
I still have 3 other stations with the same exact hardware but with an older version of **Ubuntu 12.04** and I don't have this issue.

Comment: I noticed that when I add the "now" parameter then the following message is printed:
"The system is going down for maintenance NOW!"
and when I omit it then the message is slightly different:
"The system is going down for reboot NOW!"

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same situation but could not get it solved through any of the above methods. Although there can be many causes to this problem but i solved this by disabling the USB 3.0 controller in BIOS menu.