# Reboot/Shutdown fails 

Tags: 11.10, intel, reboot

I have Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) on my PC. PC has Intel DH61CR motherboard. Whenever I try to reboot or shutdown my PC, it will freeze, vieweing only Ubuntu logo with white dots under it on violet background. I always have to use physical reset or shut down button to do what I want. Help me out please!

kern.log:

```
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.996931] init: tty4 main process (967) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997074] init: tty5 main process (973) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997202] init: tty2 main process (979) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997327] init: tty3 main process (980) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997525] init: tty6 main process (982) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997730] init: irqbalance main process (1000) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.997871] init: cron main process (1010) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11046.998227] init: tty1 main process (1261) killed by TERM signal
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: [11047.024385] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (25537) terminated with status 1
Oct 17 14:37:35 ruberoid kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

dmesg

```
[   12.946207] type=1400 audit(1318840388.898:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=894 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.946437] type=1400 audit(1318840388.898:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=894 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.946577] type=1400 audit(1318840388.898:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=894 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.946679] type=1400 audit(1318840388.898:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=898 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.052754] vesafb: mode is 1400x1050x32, linelength=5632, pages=0
[   13.052755] vesafb: scrolling: redraw
[   13.052757] vesafb: Truecolor: size=0:8:8:8, shift=0:16:8:0
[   13.056229] vesafb: framebuffer at 0xe0000000, mapped to 0xffffc90006e00000, using 5824k, total 5824k
[   13.056319] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 175x65
[   13.056334] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[   13.574711] init: failsafe main process (857) killed by TERM signal
[   13.574991] init: apport pre-start process (969) terminated with status 1
[   13.578789] init: apport post-stop process (994) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: do you have squid or any proxy server installed?

Comment: Nope, not as I know.

Comment: After reboot see the log file for error that occurs during reboot or shutdown. see /var/log/kern.log or /var/log/dmesg

Comment: I added logs, i see no errors.

Comment: press Alt+F1 (return using Alt+F7). login using your account info. restart pc and see is that show any error message :  sudo shutdown -rv now

Comment: It worked fine and I know why. I found out that if I have smartcard left inside the card reader, it wont reboot correctly. If it's removed, then it will reboot fine. Is it possible somehow to configure it so that smart card won't prevent it to reboot correctly?

Comment: backup you smartcard data. format it. then try to reboot [keep card in card reader]. If may be happen becoz your smartcard is not formated  so kernel found  un-recoverable error i guess . check the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New computer hangs on shutdown/reboot, how to troubleshoot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot)

Answer (score 1):

Just open a terminal session and enter:
Code:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: or shorter: `sudo poweroff`