# Ubuntu hangs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I recently upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. My machine now hangs during the shutdown process, but can reboot just fine. If I turn off quiet and splash boot options, then the following error is displayed:

`Connection refusedId did not get the system bus. Make sure the message bus daemon is running!
Message: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/debus/system[fail]o`

That is, the `[fail]` overwrites part of the error message. I am then dropped to a root shell. Running `shutdown now` causes the same thing to happen. Running `reboot` from here still succeeds.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Setting `apci=off` has no affect
- Following the directions from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot) gave `FATAL: Module rt2860sta not found.`
- Following the directions from [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1862995) had no result, but stopped me from running `reboot` after being put in single-user mode; now when I do this, I get an error saying /run/lock was not mounted, a message saying the system is going to restart, and then it hangs. I can still reboot from within Ubuntu as before.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Try go to the terminal and write this:

`sudo halt`

Enter your password when prompted and press enter, and then it should shut down.

Comment: That works better -- the system halts, but it doesn't automatically power off.

Comment: You could also **sudo reboot** and then use the switch... But both are very poor ways of substituting shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing from 64bit to 32bit Ubuntu 11.10.

I tried all of the other ideas.  I tried to work on the ACPI issues, I got rid of ModemManager, I tried all combinations of halt, etc.  No dice.  So I thought if a 64bit driver was messing up the shutdown, maybe a switch back to 32bit would work.

You can do an install from live disk where Ubuntu chooses to install the distro you want while retaining your documents and many of your installed programs.  I did have to reinstall System Profiler, all of the DVD decrypt libraries, etc but that was not really too bad (I have a fast FIOS internet).

So for me the solution was to use 11.10 32bit. This will not be okay if you need the 64bit version. Good luck.