# My PC doesn't shutdown from GUI

Tags: shutdown

Since at least a month, my 11.10-64bit PC doesn't shutdown anymore from the GUI. It simply freezes on plymouth screen. If I open gnome-terminal and type "sudo poweroff", it shuts down correctly.

This is very annoying. I don't have any relevant message in the logs. It simply stops at "The system will be halted"...but it doesn't power off.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate.

This is my behaviour:

- if I type "sudo shutdown -h now", the system starts powering off until it displays "Will now halt". Then it hangs there, not powering off.

- if I type "sudo halt -p", the system powers down correclty until it shuts off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding the following line to the file /etc/default/halt:

INIT_HALT = POWEROFF

Answer (score 1):

While [that solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/108272/22949) didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04, I was able to solve the problem in another way:

I removed the Nvidia drivers, and the computer then was able to correctly shut down and restart.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to shutdown and power off the machine, you should type:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

```
-h:     Requests  that  the system be either halted or powered off after
        it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to
        the system.

-P:     Requests that the system  be  powered  off  after  it  has  been
        brought down.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I updated grub and worked fine. Launch Terminal and type the following:

```
sudo update-grub
```