# Ubuntu Precise 12.04 and 11.10 do not halt the computer completely, but 10.04 LTS does (Asus P5G41T-M)

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, shutdown, acpi

I am using an Asus P5G41T-M motherboard with Core 2 Duo E5300.

I have tried Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2, the latest daily build of 12.04 and 11.10 (the latest official), both of which act in the following strange way:

When shutting down (using `shutdown -h 0`, `halt`) they get to a point where the splash screen dots are visible, but nothing more happens and the computer doesn't power off.

`shutdown -P 0` works, halt and `shutdown -h` do not.

I've tried 10.04.4 LTS and it does behave correctly.

Using the newer releases, I've tried adding `acpi=off` and `acpi=force` to the kernel parameters followed by `update-grub`, but that didn't help.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a problem.  `shutdown -h` means you want it to at least halt and the system decides whether to power off or not (see the man page for shutdown).  `-H` means you want it to just halt, and `-P` means you want the system powered down.

If you don't want to, or can't, change the commands in your scripts or whatever, you might want to try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/108272/43660).

Answer (score 0):

If you log out first and then shutdown, it works for me. (Not ideal, I know).