# gui shutdown on acer aspire v5-573G not working

Tags: 13.10, uefi, shutdown, gui, acer

When I press the gui shutdown button, the system is not powering off, but rather just remains at splash screen. Hence, I always have to power off the machine manually holding the power button. Issuing `shutdown -h` or `shutdown -P` from command line works fine while `shutdown -H` causes the same problem as the gui shutdown.

I use ubuntu 13.10 (uefi version) on an Acer Aspire V5-573G.
Adding the line "INIT_HALT = POWEROFF" to /etc/default/halt as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107699/my-pc-doesnt-shutdown-from-gui/108272#108272) does not help.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

FIx with Ubuntu 13.10 is installed in Acer aspire v5-573 laptop, uefi boot.

```
 wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/linux-headers-3.13.0-999-generic_3.13.0-999.201312270405_amd64.deb

 wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/linux-headers-3.13.0-999_3.13.0-999.201312270405_all.deb

 wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/linux-image-3.13.0-999-generic_3.13.0-999.201312270405_amd64.deb

 sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.0-*.deb linux-image-3.13.0-*.deb
```

then reboot

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63861). Fixed in latest kernel 3.13-rc5.