# Cannot shutdown, computer freezes

Tags: 12.04, ati, shutdown

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 (near windows 7) on my laptop(Dell studio xps 1640 with Ati Radeon HD 3670) and everything is working fine, but when I want to shutdown my computer it freezes!

I don't know what to do after that, then I have to use power button to power off the computer and it's not good at all. I don't know what's the problem and I don't know how to figure this out.

I installed the graphic card driver (12.6 version) from ATI website and it fixed my problem with playing videos but I think after that this shutdown problem appears!

Would you tell me what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate [New computer hangs on shutdown/reboot, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot)

You didn't give much information to help the community solve the problem. Do you get the Ubuntu logo, or is there an error message?

A temporary fix could be `sudo shutdown -h now` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the ATI graphic card driver caused the problem. I've encourtered this problem after I installed the driver, so I've to uninstall it and my Ubuntu 12.04 works well.