# Ubuntu 13.04 - Shutdown hang at purple ubuntu loading screen

Tags: updates, 13.04, shutdown

Just updated from 12.10. Ubuntu cannot shutdown properly, **it hangs at the purple ubuntu loading screen with dots animation still moving.** It hanged about half an hour. I hold the power button to shut it down.

I happened on every boot. Please help. This is all that I know.

1/5/2013 - 6:59
I tried `sudo service lightdm restart` code, and returns in console (black screen):

```
Asking for cache data failed
Assuming drive cache: write through
```

then after a half screen of attempts, the screen black out (screen saving).

I pressed the power button and another shutdown procedure began.

IMAGES:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/sany0427q.jpg/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/10/sany0428r.jpg/

Comment: I also have this problem.
It is solved when I take out the battery from my laptop and then shut down with the power button.
Then try to boot and restart, after that the battery can be reinserted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot).

Comment: not a duplication since there is no freeze or blank screen

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem frequently! I installed a new version of ubuntu13.04 64bit.

Also, when starting the ubuntu13.04, I have to run two times of this command!

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

It seems that some driver or software problem makes it happen.

Comment: I did it, says in console `Asking for cache data fail, Assuming drive cache: WRITE THROUGH`