# The system is not shut down in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, shutdown

I try to shut Xubuntu down properly from the shut down button. However, it just goes to the black screen with the word "Xubuntu" with the "wait for state stop/waiting", and stays there all night.

The only way to shut it down is to unplug it or turn off the switch on the power supply.

Is this a Xubuntu issue or something in the BIOS? I'm running 14.04.1.

I am getting these messages:

```
* Stopping rsync deamon rsync
* speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
* Asking all remaining processes Xubuntu 14.04....
* All processes ended within 1 seconds...
ModemManager [1238] : <info> Caught . . . hutting down...

ModemManager[1238] : ModemManager is shut down.

nm-dispatcher.action: Could not get the system bus. Make sure the message ..
Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press ENTER:

the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

* Unmounting temporary filesystems...

* Deactivating swap...

* Stopping early cyrpto disks...
```

Comment: Have you read through this ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot