# ACPI Package problem on boot Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: acpi

I've been using Ubuntu for pretty long time and am quite experienced with it. But recently I discovered a new problem that I can't resolve on my own.

My system is as follows:

- AMD E-450 1.65
- AMD Radeon HD 6320 with latest ATI Catalyst linux drivers
- (AMD Catalyst 14.12 Omega linux drivers)
- Ubuntu 14.04.02 64 bit system is up to date - a fresh installation
- kernel - Linux 3.16.0-34-generic
- 4 Partitions: Swap 4GB, Ubuntu 80 GB, Windows 7 160 GB, Data over 200 GB
- using burg for system choose with better splash look

When the system is booting I see a line with:

```
[    2.459938] ACPI : [Package] has zero elements (ffff880232749800)
```

After that the system seems to work as it should maybe slower sometimes it stuck for a few sec and work again and it's quite annoying to see that kind of line under boot.

A few months back when 14.04.01 was the latest Ubuntu version everything was perfect until 14.04.02 came out. I tried every possible way to resolve that problem: I wiped and did a fresh install again, changed drivers, kernel etc. But without success. It must be something do with 14.04.02. Something seems to have changed and created the problem but I don't know what exactly.

It doesn't matter if I change drivers or even kernel version. I tried from 3.13. to 3.19 last stable and problem still is there.

When I add `acpi=off noapic` to boot line the problem is gone but the system doesn't work normally.

As I wrote above even after a fresh installation without any changes the problem still shows. I though maybe it happen after my changes in system but its not true.

I read a few topics with ACPI has zero elements but all goes to use line `acpi=off` and they were very old for Ubuntu 11.04 or 12.10.

Does anyone have a idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Resolve what exactly? You mention a few things that may or may not be related, but it remains unclear, which problem you want resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What are the problems that you are facing with `acpi=off` ? Have you tried `acpi=force` -- that has been also noted to have been helpful to some (but was causing some other problems to me)? Also, have you tried setting the `acpi=` parameter (either off or force) to BOTH `/etc/default/grub`'s 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line AND `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` line (but to only one at a time, of course!)?

Your problem doesn't seem exactly like what I've had and have. But similar enough that you might want to see if this would be the same issue.

As things are I have gotten Ubuntu installed ok with the details linked below and am having problems with powering down and the internal keyboard/trackpad. I can live with these, however -- until I've solved them.

The solution that allowed me to install Ubuntu together + details of the two (new) problems I have have -- is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624447/cannot-boot-14-04-ubuntu/634871#634871). I'll be looking next into the shutdown/reboot problem, probably using [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26601/new-computer-hangs-on-shutdown-reboot-how-to-troubleshoot) as the first step.

Hope this helps!